# How to optimize this nested loop code dealing with pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, nlp

I am new to optimization and need help improving the run time of this code. It accomplishes my task, but it takes forever. Any suggestions on improving it so it runs faster?

Here is the code:

```
def probabilistic_word_weighting(df, lookup):

    # instantiate new place holder for class weights for each text sequence in the df
    class_probabilities = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    for index, row in lookup.iterrows():
        if row.word in df.words.split():
            class_proba_ = row.class_proba.strip('][').split(', ')
            class_proba_ = [float(i) for i in class_proba_]
            class_probabilities = [a + b for a, b in zip(class_probabilities, class_proba_)]

    return class_probabilities
```

The two input df's look like this:

df

```
index                                     word
1                               i  havent  been  back 
2                                            but  its 
3                   they  used  to  get  more  closer 
4                                             no  way 
5       when  we  have  some  type  of  a  thing  for
6                and  she  had  gone  to  the  doctor 
7                                                suze 
8        the  only  time  the  parents  can  call  is
9               i  didnt  want  to  go  on  a  cruise 
10                            people  come  aint  got
```

lookup

```
index    word                               class_proba
6231    been    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.27899487]
8965    havent  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.27899487]
3270    derive  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.27899487]
7817    a       [0.0, 0.0, 7.451379, 6.552, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
3452    hello   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.000155327, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
5112    they    [0.0, 0.0, 0.00032289312, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
1012    time    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.27899487]
7468    some    [0.000193199, 0.0, 0.0, 0.000212947, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
6428    people  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.27899487
5537    scuba   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.27899487
```

What its doing is essentially iterating through each row in lookup, which contains a word and its relative class weights. If the word is found in any text sequence in df.word, then the class_probabilities for lookup.word get added to the class_probabilities variable assigned to each sequence in df.word. Its looping through every row in df for every iteration on lookup rows.

How can this be done faster?

Comment: This will mildly optimize your `for` loop: Switch to `for row in lookup.itertuples():` instead of `for index, row in lookup.iterrows():`  `itertuples` is quicker than `iterrows` Ensure that you use the `in` operator on a set rather than a list since membership testing is faster in a set. `if row.word in df.words.split():`, switch to `word_set = set(df.words.split())` (define this once outside the for loop) and then use `if row.word in word_set`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you are using `df.apply` with your function, but you can do it like this. the idea is not to redo the operation on the rows of `lookup` each time you find a corresponding word but doing it once and reshape `df` to be able to perform vectorized manipulation

1: reshape the column words of `df` with `str.split`, `stack` and `to_frame` to get a new line for each word:

```
s_df = df['words'].str.split(expand=True).stack().to_frame(name='split_word')
print (s_df.head(8))
    split_word
0 0          i
  1     havent
  2       been
  3       back
1 0        but
  1        its
2 0       they
  1       used
```

2: Reshape `lookup` by `set_index` the word column, `str.strip`, `str.split` and `astype` to get a dataframe with word as index and each value of class_proba in a column

```
split_lookup = lookup.set_index('word')['class_proba'].str.strip('][')\
                     .str.split(', ', expand=True).astype(float)
print (split_lookup.head())
          0    1         2      3         4    5    6         7
word                                                           
been    0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  5.278995
havent  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  5.278995
derive  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  5.278995
a       0.0  0.0  7.451379  6.552  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.000000
hello   0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.000  0.000155  0.0  0.0  0.000000
```

3: `Merge` both, `drop` the unnecessary column and `groupby` the level=0 being the original index of `df` and `sum`

```
df_proba = s_df.merge(split_lookup, how='left',
                      left_on='split_word', right_index=True)\
               .drop('split_word', axis=1)\
               .groupby(level=0).sum()
print (df_proba.head())
          0    1         2         3    4    5    6         7
0  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0  10.55799
1  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.00000
2  0.000000  0.0  0.000323  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.00000
3  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.00000
4  0.000193  0.0  7.451379  6.552213  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.00000
```

4: finally, convert to a list and reassign to the original df with `to_numpy` and `tolist`:

```
df['class_proba'] = df_proba.to_numpy().tolist()
print (df.head())
                                           words  \
0                          i  havent  been  back   
1                                       but  its   
2              they  used  to  get  more  closer   
3                                        no  way   
4  when  we  have  some  type  of  a  thing  for   

                                         class_proba  
0   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.55798974]  
1           [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
2  [0.0, 0.0, 0.00032289312, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...  
3           [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]  
4  [0.000193199, 0.0, 7.451379, 6.552212946999999...
```

Comment: This is magic, thank you. It not only solved my problem, but made optimization more approachable.

Comment: @connor449 glad it helps :) I did some timing and on the input, it is almost twice faster, but if you increase the size of df 10 times then it becomes more than 14 time faster!